# When writing a gem, how do you get access to helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For a gem, i'm writing, I want to be able to access current_user (most auth systems have this helper)

What are some ways of doing that?

the thing that the controller includes to get current_user is this  `AuthenticatedSystem`
not sure how the helpers get access to it's contents

*I'm using RestfulAuth

Answer (score 0):

If your gem has modules that get included on controllers, you can test if the method is available:

```
self.respond_to?( :current_user )
```

And if it is just call it. If your gem really needs it it would even raise an error if the method is not available.

Comment: the thing that the controller includes to get current_user is this   include AuthenticatedSystem
not sure how the helpers get access to it's contents

Comment: Not always, there are many different gems that use it, like Devise. If your gem has modules that get inclulded in the controller you can just assume the method is there (if this is a requirement). But this is true only on controllers, usually (in some cases you'll have it in the views also).